# Which secret societies is JFK denouncing in this speech?

Tags: war, jfk, illuminati

I have a few friends who are strong believers of the existence of illuminati/nwo threats, and I occasionally am shown a video or two that is supposed to provide evidence of such.

Whether such a group is out there or not, in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YafZkjiMpjU) JFK alludes to secret societies and a great conspiracy behind the scenes.

As he says in his speech:

> "For we are opposed around the world by **a monolithic and ruthless conspiracy** that relies primarily on covert means for expanding its sphere of influence"
>
> ...
>
> "It is a system which has conscripted vast human and material resources into the building of a tightly knit, highly efficient machine"
>
> ...
>
> "Its preparations are **concealed, not published**. Its mistakes are buried, not headlined"

My first intuition, given the historical context, is that this speech is about Marxist/Communist secret societies of the time (which the US was very active in opposing), and the dangers of ideological intolerance, which is why he says he is opposed to "an office of war" and "censorship" of any kind.

I think this would be a sane view, based on another segment where he states the "machine"

> "...conducts the Cold War, in short, with a war-time discipline no democracy would ever hope or wish to match"

The rest of the internet, however, appears to believe that this speech is most likely the cause of his assassination, and proof of the NWO conspiracy.

**Is JFK's speech exposing a secret agenda driven by NWO groups such as the illuminati?**

NOTE: full speech available at [jfklibrary](https://www.jfklibrary.org/Research/Research-Aids/JFK-Speeches/American-Newspaper-Publishers-Association_19610427.aspx)

Comment: If the text of the full speech you link to is not enough to conclude either way, what would be sufficient proof?

Comment: Doesn't the link to the full speech at jfklibrary give enough context to answer your question? Are you going to write the answer yourself?

Comment: Maybe his warning was not focused on any specific group, but was meant to frighten people into looking for any such group.

Comment: What are illuminati/nwo threats?  What is NWO?

Comment: military industrial complex, not a secret society.  Read the whole text.  Many of the snips on the internet are pieced together.

Comment: Illuminati - existed and fell apart (A government edict dated 2 March 1785 "seems to have been deathblow to the Illuminati in Bavaria").  NWO isn't a thing.  There is nobody who goes around saying they are NWO (except wrestlers?).  There are people who claim that groups that sum up to a NWO group - but since there isn't agreement on who those groups are and they don't self identify, how could you argue for or against?  Any group that has does anything that someone is against, they get labeled as NWO.  Communists say capitalists are NWO, capitalists say Communists are NWO...

Comment: @phoog the NWO I know is a research institute where some friends of mine have worked :D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands_Organisation_for_Scientific_Research

Comment: @SomeFreemason NWO is a thing, but probably not the one OP means :D (see above)